# Impersonate Azure AD User

Tags: azure-active-directory, kerberos, impersonation, delegation

I have an Azure domain system that is hooked to user machines and servers. I have to have windows authentication enabled for an ASP.NET app (APP#1) on one of the servers so users who have logged on to their machines using the AAD can seamlessly access the app.

However, I have to have another app (APP#2) on the same server that should be able to access the APP#1 as any user (impersonation) of the same AD tenant. The user can be presented with a login page (preferably some sort of Azure login page). Is there any way the APP#2 can store a token using which it can access APP#1 (which only works using Kerberos or NTLM authentication).

I have tried to set up the Application Proxy Connector offered by Azure. But this seems to be overkill as in this case, both the apps are in the same server and no need for an extra round trip.

Can somebody suggest a viable solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a dedicated service account, configure protocol transition and constrained delegation. Add SPNs which you want delegate to. Impersonate from your service account to your user, perform operation, release impersonated credentials.